# python - different behavior in console and in wsgi app

Tags: python, background-process, popen

I have setup python in windows server 2008 and I'm using cherrypy with wsgi.

First of all, I have a math program that only runs on windows. I can pass a file with commands to this program:

```
#file.txt
sum(2+2)
writeinfile("output.txt")

#in cmd/powershell
C:\>PATH_TO_FOLDER\program.exe file.txt

#that outputs some lines in console
... compiling
... solving
... saving
```

and then I got my output file with the proper result. I can also read values from a DB using an ODBC method provided by this program like this:

```
#file2.txt
values = ODBC()
sum(values)
writeinfile("output2.txt")

#in cmd/powershell
C:\>PATH_TO_FOLDER\program.exe file2.txt

#also outputs the lines mentioned in the first example
```

and this also works. So I decided to fill this txt files via web browser. In order to do that, I tested the command mentioned before like this in console

```
>>> from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
>>> program = "C:\\PATH_TO_FOLDER\\program.exe"
>>> txt = "C:\\PATH_TO_FILE\\file2.txt"
>>> print Popen([program, txt], shell=True, stdout=PIPE).stdout.read()
  ... compiling
  ... solving
  ... saving
```

And it also generates "output2.txt", so it seems to work as expected. Knowing this, I used cherrypy in order to have something in my browser:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import cherrypy

class Solver(object):
    @cherrypy.expose:
    def process_solver(self):
        program = "C:\\PATH_TO_FOLDER\\program.exe"
        txt = "C:\\PATH_TO_FILE\\file2.txt"
        p = Popen([program, txt], shell = True, stdout = PIPE)
        return p.stdout.read()

application = cherrypy.Application(Solver(), script_name = None, config = None)
```

and when I go to `http:/localhost/process_solver` I only get the following:

```
... compiling
```

but the file "output2.txt" has been created ... with nothing inside.

So, why is it happening? why does console behaves in a way and my script in other?

Thanks in advance

Comment: We can't see any of your _code_ here.  We have _no idea_ what is going on in `program.exe`.  How are we supposed to help you troubleshoot?

Comment: I don't have the source code of it, it's an exe program in windows. As I mentioned, I only want to fill the txt file and then run the program by using command line